# Dynatree expand-button collide with $(document).click

Tags: jquery

Dynatree script: **https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/** 
Dynatree demo **http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html**

**Problem:** If put the Dynatree in a toggeling div that have the functionality to close when click at document/outside div (see code below) there is a problem, when click at a expand/minimize button in the Dynatree the div close. So the expand/minimize buttons in the list must be a part of the document while for example the labels/titles are not (becuse they are clickable without the div closes).

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.div').hide();
})
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you need to do is to prevent the click event on the button from propagating it's event up the hierarchy.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$('.dynatree-button').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Alternatively you could make sure that your clicks aren't occurring on dynatree links

```
$(document).click(function () {
    if ( $(this).not('.dynatree-button') ) {
      $('.div').hide();
    }
});
```